# IP conflicts mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, duplicates

I am building a site where the users are allowed to have one account per IP.

I am looking for a way to display users with the same IP using PDO mysql...

Here is what I got...

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("SELECT login_ip FROM accounts");
$q -> execute();
$duplicate = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will fetch everyones' IP addresses. How can I then see if there is any exact matches and show them??

Comment: I don't know where you are but unless you pay extra in the UK your IP will be dynamic meaning your user will not have the same IP everytime they visit. Best of this i'd say your idea is not a good idea.

Comment: Save a cookie, report if multi-logging, hunt, kill.

Comment: That sucks for people behind a NAT.  All of them will show up as the same IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT login_ip, COUNT(login_ip) AS occurences
FROM accounts
GROUP BY login_ip
HAVING ( COUNT(login_ip) > 1 )
```

This will list you all possible duplicate IPs.

Comment: Thank you, even if my question was not a good idea, it is still nice to know :)